# Java - use methods from another class

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
 interface Paint {
    float paintPerSurfaceUnit = (float) 0.3;
 }

 class PaintThings implements Paint {
    public float paint_sphere(Sphere obj){
        return (obj.area() * paintPerSurfaceUnit);
     }

  }

  class Sphere extends Shape {
    int radius;
    public float area(){
        return (float) (4*3.14*radius*radius);
    }
  }
```

How can I access "paint_sphere" in main with Sphere object ?

Comment: You need an instance of `PaintThings`

Comment: With the sphere class or object?

Comment: `new PaintThings().paint_sphere(mySphere);` where `mySphere` is your Sphere object.

Comment: Object, Sphere bigBall = new Sphere();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code, the method paint instanciate the PaintThings and pass the object Shape via this

```
  class Sphere extends Shape {
    int radius;
    public float area(){
        return (float) (4*3.14*radius*radius);
    }
    public float paint(){
        return new PaintThings().paint_sphere(this);
    }
```

but the better way is to pass the PaintThing object via the constructor to reduce coupling

```
  class Sphere extends Shape {
    int radius;
    Paint paint;
    Sphere(Paint paint){
    this.paint = paint;
    }
    public float area(){
        return (float) (4*3.14*radius*radius);
    }
    public float paint(){
        return paint.paint_sphere(this);
    }
```

Comment: He deosn't want to use two classes

Comment: YES! It's perfect, Thank you very much!,

Comment: I want pain shape without make PaintThings object

Comment: This deserves a golden facepalm

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here :
Either make your function static

```
class PaintThings implements Paint {
    static public float paint_sphere(Sphere obj){
        return (obj.area() * paintPerSurfaceUnit);
    }
}
```

And call it like that

```
mySphere sphere = new Sphere();
PaintThings.paintSphere(yourSphere);
```

Or make an object of Paint too :

```
PaintThings myPainter = new PaintThings();
mySphere sphere = new Sphere();
myPainter.paint_sphere(mySphere);
```

Comment: If `paint_sphere()` is made static then `paintPerSurfaceUnit` must be static too

Comment: I want something like this in main: System.out.println(PaintThings().paint_sphere(bigBall));

Comment: as @Arijoon said, use my first solution and make `paintPerSurfaceUnit` static, but this is weird...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use an instance of a `PaintThings`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere();
    PaintThings paintthings = new PaintThings();
    paintthings.paint_sphere(sphere);
}
```

Make sure to pass a `Sphere` into the `paint_sphere(Sphere)` method.

Comment: I don't want make PaintThink object, I want use in System Print

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What is System Print?